# Troubleshooting Issues with Laravel Tests and JWT Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-10

I am facing some kind of tricky issue here. The login method returns a token does work good when the request is made from send via Insomnia. This code defines a public function named login that receives a Request object and returns a JsonResponse object.
This code defines a public function named login that receives a Request object and returns a `JsonResponse` object.

Inside the function, it first checks if the user's credentials are valid by calling the `authenticateUser` method. If the credentials are invalid, it returns a JSON response with the message "Credenciais inválidas" and a status code of 401.

Next, it gets the authenticated user using the `Auth::user()` method.

Then, it checks if the user has enabled two-factor authentication by checking the `google2fa_secret` property. If the `google2fa_secret` is empty or null, it returns a JSON response asking the user to enable two-factor authentication.

Finally, if the user has enabled two-factor authentication, it generates a JWT token using the `JWTAuth::attempt` method with the user's email and password, and returns a JSON response with the generated token.

Overall, this code snippet represents a login functionality that checks the user's credentials, verifies if two-factor authentication is enabled, and returns a token if the login is successful.

This is the login method:

```
public function login(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    if (!$this->authenticateUser($request)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Credenciais inválidas'], 401);
    }

    $user = Auth::user();

    if (!$user->google2fa_secret) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Você ainda não habilitou a autenticação em duas etapas. Por favor, habilite para continuar.']);
    }

    return response()->json(['token' => JWTAuth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))]);
}
```

This is the private method:

```
private function authenticateUser(Request $request): bool
{
    return JWTAuth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));
}
```

It works just fine, but:

This test creates a user and try to log in using JWT to generate the token.

```
public function testLogin()
{
    $randomBytes = random_bytes(10);
    $google2faSecret = Base32::encodeUpper($randomBytes);

    $user = User::factory()->create([
        'name' => 'Dude',
        'email' => 'dude@mail.com',
        'password' => '123456',
        'google2fa_secret' => $google2faSecret,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
    ]);

    $user->assignRole('vendor');

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->json('POST', '/api/login', [
        'email' => $user->email,
        'password' => $user->password,
    ]);

    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $response->assertJson(['token' => $response->json('token')]);
}
```

This method returns a token when the request is made from Insomnia:

```
private function authenticateUser(Request $request)
{
    $json = JWTAuth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));

    dd($json);
}
```

But when I run a test (`sail artisan test`), the `dd($token)`, returns `false` and I can't figure out why.

I am running a Laravel 10 app, PHP 8.2, and Tymon\JWTAuth
The `JWT_SECRET` is on the `.env.testing` file!

Comment: What do you have setup on your test? Share your test. Do you have a user and password when running the test?

Comment: When you're using `actingAs` it already logs you in, which might conflict with the authentication process, short-circuiting it somewhere, for example. Should a logged in user be authenticated again? I would also suggest looking through the tests here https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/2.x/tests/Providers/Auth/IlluminateTest.php

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!
First, added `JWTAuth::from($user);` as follows:

```
public function testLogin()
{
    $randomBytes = random_bytes(10);
    $google2faSecret = Base32::encodeUpper($randomBytes);

    $user = User::factory()->create([
        'name' => 'Ronaldo',
        'email' => 'dude@mail.com.br',
        'password' => '123456',
        'google2fa_secret' => $google2faSecret,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
    ]);

    $user->assignRole('vendor');
    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

    $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/login', [
        'email' => $user->email,
        'password' => $user->password,
        'token' => $token,
    ]);
    
    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $response->assertJson(['token' => $response->json('token')]);
}
```

And, at the `login()` added a `if` condition:

```
public function login(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    if (env('APP_ENV') !== 'testing') {
        if (!$this->authenticateUser($request)) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Credenciais inválidas'], 401);
        }
    }

    $user = Auth::user();

    if (!$user->google2fa_secret) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Você ainda não habilitou a autenticação em duas etapas. Por favor, habilite para continuar.']);
    }

    return response()->json(['token' => JWTAuth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))]);
}
```

Comment: How does passing token as a part request mimic real life authentication process? Also a quick question why use `$this->json('POST'` instead of `$this->post`?